# Why does this algorithm only give out 2's for values? Also, I get null pointer exceptions

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a Blackjack game, and I'm trying to write a method to randomly determine the face on the card. My method is:

```
  public String determineFace(){
    String f = null;

    if ( (int) Math.random() * 12  == 0){
      f = "2";
    }
    if ( (int) Math.random() * 12  == 1){
      f = "3";
    }
    if ( (int) Math.random() * 12  == 2){
      f = "4";
    }
    if ( (int) Math.random() * 12  == 3){
      f = "5";
    }
    if ( (int) Math.random() * 12  == 4){
      f = "6";
    }
    if ( (int) Math.random() * 12  == 5){
      f = "7";
    }
    if ( (int) Math.random() * 12  == 6){
      f = "8";
    }
    if ( (int) Math.random() * 12  == 7){
      f = "9";
    }
    if ( (int) Math.random() * 12  == 8){
      f = "10";
    }
    if ((int) Math.random() * 12 == 9){
      f = "J";
    }
    if ((int) Math.random() * 12 == 10){
      f = "Q";
    }
    if ((int) Math.random() * 12 == 11){
      f = "K";
    }
    if ((int) Math.random() * 12 == 12){
      f = "A";
    }
    return f;
  }
```

but when I instantiate a card, I only get values of "2". My method for Suit works fine; which is;

```
  public static Suit determineSuit(){
    if ( (int) (Math.random() * 3) == 0){
      return Suit.CLUBS;
    }
    else if ((int) (Math.random() * 3) == 1){
      return Suit.DIAMONDS;
   } 
    else if ((int)(Math.random() * 3) == 2){
      return Suit.HEARTS;
    }
    else{
      return Suit.SPADES;
    }
  }
```

How can I get my determineFace() method to work properly?

Also, as I instantiate Cards for test cases, the constructor and instance vars being:

```
  private CardValue value;
  private Suit suit;

  public Card(){
    this.value = new CardValue(determineFace());
    this.suit = determineSuit();

  }
```

I sometimes get NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: You forgot some parentheses, `(int) Math.random()` is already zero

Comment: If you ever think to yourself "man I'm writing the same-looking code over and over"... then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Side note: check your suits method. The four suits are not returned with equal probability.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart you made me smile :) ahahaha, you are so right, I know is not so good to provide a whole complete different solution, but I just could not see 13 if consecutively, was harder than me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suit method is also invalid. First of all you should multiply by 4, not 3. Secondly, even if you fix that, you're generating a new random number every time so your suit distribution would look like this:

```
1/4 = 25% clubs
(1/4)*(3/4) = 18.75% diamonds
(1/4)*(9/16) = 14.0625% hearts
The remaining = 42.1875% spades
```

Not that it matters in blackjack, just note you'll be seeing a ton of spades and not many hearts and diamonds, and that you should only call Math.random() once like this:

```
public static Suit determineSuit(){
  int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
  if (randNum == 0){
    return Suit.CLUBS;
  }
  else if (randNum == 1){
    return Suit.DIAMONDS;
  } 
  else if (randNum == 2){
    return Suit.HEARTS;
  }
  else{
    return Suit.SPADES;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! can you explain the math on the first bloc of code you got?

Comment: @zach, will my solution have the same problem?

Comment: @DamianLattenero yours is good because you only generate the random number once.

Comment: @Derry the math for that is you check to see if a random number is in 1/4 of the population, so 1/4 for clubs. 3/4 of the time it gets passed the clubs generation, and of that 3/4, 1/4 of the time it will pick diamonds, so you take (3/4)*(1/4) because they are two independent random events and p(a and b) = p(a)*p(b) for independent random events. The probability of getting to the heart code is (3/4)*(3/4) = 9/16 and when you get there you're 1/4 to pick hearts. Finally spades is just 1-p(clubs)-p(diamonds)-p(spades)

Answer (score 2):

```
(int) Math.random()
```

This always generate 0 you should generate 0<=x<13
Try this instead

```
(int)(Math.random()*13)
```

Notice that the extra parantheses in the second one.

Comment: well, that fix the problem indeed... Nice one ugur

Comment: are you saying that if I replace all the 'if ((int) Math.random() * 12 == v)' with 'if ((int)(Math.random()*13) == v) ' then the values will work out with equal prob?

Answer (score 2):

If you allow me, I could offer another way to do the same, something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.print(determineFace() + determineSuit());
  }

  public static String determineFace(){

    Random rn = new Random();

    int min = 2;
    int max = 12;

    return "" + (rn.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min);

  }

  public static Suit determineSuit(){
    Random rn = new Random();
    Suit t = null;

    switch (rn.nextInt(Suit.values().length)) {
      case 0: 
        t = Suit.CLUBS;
      break;
      case 1:
        t = Suit.DIAMONDS;
      break;
      case 2:
        t = Suit.HEARTS;
      break;
      case 3:
        t = Suit.SPADES;
      break;
    }
    return t;

  }




}

enum Suit{

  CLUBS,
  DIAMONDS,
  HEARTS,
  SPADES

}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling this code? You haven't assigned anything to `rand`.

Comment: Also, the scope of `rand` is too narrow.

Comment: @LewBloch you are totally right, I wrote it here, I will find a way to compile it sorry my bad, I tried to provide some alternative quickly

Comment: I suggest instantiating `rand` as an instance variable.

Comment: How about `switch (rand.nextInt(Suit.values().length)) { case 0: ...}`?

Comment: @LewBloch it's a pleasure now see it! Look the "before" and "after", it's like take a shower after a month haha

Comment: Cases can only run from `0` through `3`, inclusive.

Comment: @LewBloch I followed your advice and looked into a compiler online, tons of mini errors I had, I finally update the final answer, thanks a lot ?çh!

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend only calling Math.random once and assigning the value to a variable before your if statements, otherwise you will get unexpected results.

i.e:

```
int rand = (int)(Math.random()*13)
if ( rand == 0){
   f = "2";
} ... etc
```